# How do I force compiler to use aggregate init instead of constructor

Tags: c++

Consider following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    int a, b;

    Test(int, int)
    {
        a = b = 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test v {1, 1};
    std::cout << v.a << ' ' << v.b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Here `{1, 1}` calls the `Test(int, int)` constructor and thus output is `0 0` .

Is it possible to force compiler to aggregate initialize `v` so that output would be `1 1`?

At this moment I use separate method to initialize fileds directly, like:

```
struct Test
{
    ...
    static Test NewTest(int x, int y)
    {
        Test ret;
        ret.a = x;
        ret.b = y;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there a nicer way to do it.

Comment: Why? Why would you make a constructor that takes parameters, then ignores them and uses `0` anyway? In fact you will likely get "unused formal parameter" warnings on most compilers.

Comment: If you provide some constructors, usually you are telling users, these are the only ways of creating this object.

Comment: @Cyber it's just a testcase. Actual code does some computations and then assigns values to fields.

Comment: @NeilKirk Don't worry, I need to initialize memebers directly only inside the class, to implement methods that return instances of this class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aggregate initialization requires the type to be an aggregate. Having a user-declared constructor makes the type a non-aggregate, so no this isn't possible. If you remove the constructor then your type will become an aggregate, and aggregate-initialization will occur.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to force compiler to aggregate initialize `v` so that output would be `1 1`?

One way to do that would be to remove the constructor completely.

```
struct Test
{
    int a, b;
};
```